# Interacting with Application while it's running in C

Tags: c, daemon, signals

I've been looking for an answer to this question for a while now. I have written a small, lightweight server and it runs just fine really. No problems there; however, there's some things I would like to do with the application while it's actually running. For example: `server stop` to obviously halt the server.

Perhaps I should be looking at making a daemon for my server? The platform it runs on is Linux, and I have no intentions of porting to non-POSIX platforms, so Windows isn't relevant here.

But yes, to summarize my question: **how to make my application receive 'arguments' or 'tasks'  from outside (such as the command line, or a different application)**

Cheers in advance, as I know StackOverflow is always ready with a solid, quick answer,

/Jesse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variety of options. One popular solution is to use POSIX-style [signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29). Basically you install a signal handler and react to signals.

If that is too simplistic (because e.g. you need to accept parameters), you could also let your daemon open a socket where it listens for commands. You then write a small helper program to send commands to the socket. You can also do something similar using a named pipe.

Basically what you are looking for is called [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC). The Wikipedia page may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested into looking into [Signal Handling](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html), which is a common method that applications such as the [Apache web server use to handle requests like this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html).

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX platforms, a simple way to control a running application is to use *signals*. For example, you could write a handler for the SIGUSR1 signal that does something specific in the context of your server. You can send a signal like this:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 $pid
```

where `$pid` is the pid of your running server. A limitation of the signal method is there isn't any direct way to send any other information along with the signal. However, indirectly the server can act upon a signal by reloading a configuration file, for example.

For more complex control, another way to control a running server is to embed a simple web server inside it. If you set up that web server to listen on port 8080 for example, you would be able to talk to it by going to

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

in your browser. This method allows a near infinite number of possibilities for monitoring and control.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers, from easy to complex:

- Use signal(3) handlers. Meant for this purpose to do something. The `kill`(1) command will transmit the signal from the outside.
- Monitor a file for changes and inspect what's in there, do something depending on what's in there
- Use an IPC protocol that allows other applications to talk to you. Broad topic, widely discussed on the web.
- Make it a client/server architecture in which commands can be sent through TCP/UDP.

Comment: Note that point 2 (using a file), while relatively simple to implement, can be tricky to get right due to race conditions (reading a half-finished file etc.).